# How do I get only the integer from my list?

Tags: python, list, integer

I need help with getting only the integer from the following in Python 3.7 in the VS Code editor.

This code is for a black jack game. First I am printing a random card e.g. `[('Nine', 9), 'Spade']`. How do I get just the 9? So I can calculate a score?

```
import random

suit = {'Jack': 10, 'Queen': 10, 'King': 10, 'Ace': 
[1,11],'Two':2,'Three':3,
'Four':4,'Five':5,'Six':6,'Seven':7,'Eight':8,'Nine':9}
symb = ['Spade','Clubs','Heart','Diamonds']

player_hand = random.sample(suit.items(), 1) + random.sample(symb, 1)

print(player_hand)

print(player_hand[1])

# only gives me (rand symbol e.g.'Spade','Clubs','Heart','Diamonds')
```

Comment: you need the second item in the first list item. use : `print(player_hand[0][1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second print is almost correct. However since player_hand is of this form: `(string, integer), string]`, you need to retrieve the second item from the tuple. Thus if you only want to retrieve the number, do `player_hand[0][1]`.